# Determine which Controls are in the Header/Footer of an Access form via VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with labels in the header and in the footer and description. I just want to list the labels from the header and avoid the others from the footer and description sections. I have the code that loops into the controls (`For Each control in Form.Controls`), what I need now is just to separate the header labels from the others.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which Header section you are talking about, you probably want either:

> For Each ctl In Me.*FormHeader*.Controls

Or:

> For Each ctl In Me.*PageHeaderSection*.Controls

However, through discussion in comments it was identified that you are looking to iterate through all of the controls in a form that is a subform in another form, in that case you would use the following:

> Forms![frmMainForm]![frmSubForm].Form.FormHeader.Controls

Comment: `.FormHeader` and `.PageHeaderSection` only appear in IntelliSense if the form actually has a Form Header or a Page Header, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation Gord!

Comment: thanks David for your quick assistance. as I told to Gord unfortunately, FormHeader does not exists in my Access VBA.

Comment: Thor, as Gord replied above.. and will probably reply to your other comment, .FormHeader exists if your form has a FormHeader. If you are using a PageHeaderSection, then you would use PageHeaderSection. Regardless, what you want to do is identify the specific type of section you are using and use Me.*SectionName*.Controls

Comment: David. I opened the subform project and it says FormHeader, not PageHeader. but anyway I separated the labels from the header from the others. when I list those lables it doens not come in the same order as they are in the subform. do you know how to take them in the same order as in the form, considering that they are labels and don't have tab order? cheers.

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing like that. It is either listed alphabetically or in the order they were added to the form.


However, after reading your clarification to Gord, you probably want:


    For Each c In Forms![frmMainForm]![frmSubForm].Form.FormHeader.Controls

Comment: no David. it doesn't work. but I solved this by renaming the labels from the header and filtering with the if clause. now, I really need to take the labels with the same order, from left to right, as in the form. if you know, i'd appreciate. cheers.

Comment: The name of the header and footer could be different.

Answer (score 0):

The Section property from the form or report allow to access to a particular section. It is recommended you use the constants to make your code easier to read.

```
Form_Test.Section(acDetail).Controls.Count

Form_Test.Section(acheader).Controls.Count
Form_Test.Section(acFooter).Controls.Count

Form_Test.Section(acPageHeader).Controls.Count
Form_Test.Section(acPageHeader).Controls.Count
```